# how can I use tick event in mvc4.in web page protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I use tick event in MVC4. In web page I am using this:

```
 protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)        
 {                     
 }
```

It will reload the page after 300,000 time interval. I am new in MVC. I am using razor engine.

Answer (score 1):

Why do it server-side?

You can use Meta Refresh:

```
<!-- Refresh after 30 seconds -->
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
```

Or, if you prefer, Javascript:

```
<script>
  setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.reload();
  }, 30e3); // 30 seconds
</script>
```